# Сказать то - значит ничего не сказать. Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый день. Не могу нигде найти правописание фразы "Сказать что-то - значит ничего не сказать". Нужна ли запятая после слова "значит"? В некоторых текстах видел, как употребляется с запятой, в других - без.

Comment: Сказать "Дважды два" значит сказать "два плюс два".

Comment: Здесь необходимо тире. В позиции между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными инфинитивом, "значит" - связка.

Comment: Если Вы правы, тогда сформулируйте моё предложение в прошедшем времени.

Comment: Это не я права, это Розенталь и Лопатин: "Тире ставится перед словами это, это есть, значит, это значит, вот, присоединяющими сказуемое к подлежащему: Понять — значит простить"; "Понять человека — значит простить (значит — связка в сказуемом)". Попробуйте перевести в прошедшее время другую связку: Понять - это простить. Сверхнаучные задачи ставите:)

Comment: Из Валгиной ("Современный рус. яз."): "В роли связки могут выступать частицы это, вот, значит, это значит".

Comment: По мнению авторов одного из учебников, предложение "To live is to work." эквивалентно предложению "Жить (это) значит работать.". А Вы как думаете?

Comment: Я не английский филолог - точно не скажу, как переводится is: это, значит или это значит. Но если у авторов учебника перед "значит" нет тире, они допустили ошибку. Такое бывает: ошибки встречаются даже в учебниках по русской пунктуации.

Comment: Dear tat. Вам осталось догадаться, что Розенталь, Лопатин, Валгина, Вы и Ваш покорный слуга сопособны совершать ошибки.

P.S. Между прочим, по мнению христиан, Христос - единственный человек, который не способен совершить ни одной ошибки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Значит* может быть вводным словом (в значении «стало быть, выходит, следовательно»), союзом (соединяет части сложного предложения), связкой (между подлежащим и сказуемым) и сказуемым (в значении «означает»).

Вводное слово «значит» обособляется: *Так, значит, вы сегодня не можете прийти?*

Перед связкой «значит» ставится тире: *Бороться — значит победить.*

Сказуемое «значит» никакими знаками не выделяется: *Что значит талант?*

А вот с союзом «значит» непросто: справочники дают противоречивые рекомендации, так как пунктуационная норма меняется.

Согласно Розенталю, союз «значит» выделяется запятыми, в том числе и в составе двойного союза «если… значит»: *Если наступит весна, значит, будет тепло. Прозвенел звонок, значит, урок кончился.*

«Справочник по пунктуации» на Gramota.ru также советует выделять союз «значит» запятой: «Сближаясь по значению с вводными словами «следовательно», «таким образом», союз «значит» отделяется запятой (реже тире) от последующей части предложения: *А если он в таком состоянии, что и чинить нельзя, значит, надо выбросить*».

Но в «Полном академическом справочнике» Лопатина союз «значит» запятыми не выделяется: *На небе собираются тучи, значит будет дождь.*

В «Словаре вводных слов» 2009 года союз «значит» также не выделяется запятыми. Таким образом, невыделение союза «значит» запятыми следует считать современной пунктуационной нормой.

В предложении *Сказать что-то — значит ничего не сказать* «значит» — связка между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными инфинитивом. Запятая не нужна.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Иногда трудно различить вводное слово и союз «значит». Это связано с тем, что синоним, по которому мы опознаем вводное слово — «следовательно», — сам может быть и вводным, и союзом (в значении «поэтому»).

Формальный критерий разграничения такой: «значит» вводное внутри простого предложения или в абсолютном начале предложения, союз — между частями сложного предложения.

Answer (score 2):

"В «Словаре вводных слов» 2009 года союз «значит» также не выделяется запятыми. Таким образом, невыделение союза «значит» запятыми следует считать современной пунктуационной нормой".

А можно ли с этим согласиться? Пунктуационные нормы должны иметь грамматическое обоснование: если нормы становятся "современными", то им должна соответствовать "современная" грамматика или современное понимание грамматики.

В грамматике-80 есть тема, посвященная союзам - в частности, там говорится о том, что значение союза может уточняться с помощью коррелятов, и в роли коррелята может выступать слово "значит". Корреляция заключается в актуализации (усилении) причинного значения условного союза.

Например, есть условный союз ЕСЛИ...ТО, и есть союзы ЕСЛИ...ТО,ЗНАЧИТ и  ЕСЛИ...ЗНАЧИТ. Коррелят может находиться как в первой части, так и во второй части предложения: "Стало быть, я с ним приятель большой, коли знаю". "Если сразу не приехал, значит, не так уж стремился к сыну".

Таким образом, коррелят, входя в состав союза, по-прежнему обособлялся на правах вводного слова, и все считали это вполне логичным.  Однако в наше время все эти объяснения стали казаться очень утомительными для понимания, и намного легче было сказать, что перед нами просто союз, а что за союз, с каким значением - неважно. И сколько книг (классических и современных) придется переписать под "современную норму"- неважно тоже.

Например: Послал мне крест, значит, меня он любит (Тургенев). Раз вы читаете это письмецо, значит, я вас уже покинул (Акунин).

В любом случае, вопрос отнюдь не кажется решенным и сделать окончательный вывод, что "следует считать нормой...", еще рано. В самых последних изданиях, посвященных проблемам пунктуации, запятая после ЗНАЧИТ ставится.

Comment: Конечно, пока не проведена реформа языка, нормы будут сосуществовать. Но на данный момент практики (не ученые) ориентируются на ПАС как на официальную позицию Академии наук. Кстати, вопрос: в печатном издании Грамматики-80 примеры с коррелятом "значит" тоже то с запятой, то без, как и в электронном варианте?